# Event conflicts w/ google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a complete newbie to google analytics, new like I was put on a project yesterday and I've been combing through docs trying to figure out what's wrong with this _trackEvent that I'm trying to set up.

Here's the setup:
  I have a drupal site that has had some custom events set up. One of the events that we track is outbound links, and that works great. What we want to do is start creating special cases for some of these links. So for example I have a live chat button w/ this code:

```
<a href='url/to/chat 
  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','LiveChat','btnClick',this.href]);
  setTimeout(function(){this.newWindow = window.open(this.href);
  this.newWindow.focus(); 
  this.newWindow.opener=window;},200);
  return false;"><img alt='Live Chat Software' src='src/url' border='0'></a>
```

so what I did is ran the calls through the ga_debug.js. This is the output I got

```
_gaq.push processing "_trackEvent" for args: 
  "[Outbound links,Click,outgoing/url]": Track Event 
  Tracking beacon sent!
```

This means that an event is getting sent on click. So I'm curious why it's sending an Outbound Links event rather than my LiveChat event? Could it be scoping issues? Not sure, as I know the outbound links is defined at a global level. Anyone have any suggestions/insights/opinions?  Before berating me about code, I have inherited this project and I'm just trying to understand it better.

thank you,
Brodie

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that it was a scoping issue. When they had originally set us up the bomb the click event was registered to the body as opposed to being an inline. So that was eating the inline event.

lesson learned: double check scoping

tools that helped
ga_debug.js